Why does my tkinter app resize after running a pywebview window?
I have a simple tkinter app with 2 buttons. I'm using 1 button to open a pywebview window to a website. Initially, the 2nd button was to close this window, however I kept getting a problem where the tkinter app would become unresponsive, so these buttons were unclickable.
I changed the 2nd button's command to just close the tkinter app, so that's fine. In both instances, the window opens successfully, and the website loads, but:

the tkinter app is still unresponsive in both scenarios
the tkinter app resizes. it gets smaller, and looks weird. this is my biggest problem, and it also happens in both scenarios.

I'm ok with the app being unresponsive, because I'm ok with closing the window 1st before continuing to the app, but I'm not ok with the resizing. I also notice it happens on the 1st window opening, then stays the same small size no matter how many times I open the the window.
My questions are:

Is there a way to open the pywebview window without the tkinter app becoming unresponsive?
Is there a way to open the pywebview window without the tkinter app resizing?
If not pywebview, what other python web browser package could I use?
Should I add a thread somewhere?

ps. I know "it would be better to ditch tkinter, and move to a better python gui framework", but it's too late now. I can always just have the button open the link in Chrome, but I... I don't want that.
Also, I added stuff like root.wm_state("normal") to just try something.
import tkinter as tk
import webview

#Global variable to hold the webview window
webview_window = None

def load_my_url(window, url):
    #change url:
    window.load_url(url)

#Function to create the webview window
def create_my_webview_window():
    global webview_window
    if webview_window is None:
        width, height = 400, 750
        root.wm_deiconify()
        webview_window = webview.create_window(title='My Website', width=width, height=height,
x=300, y=0, on_top=True, resizable=False, min_size=(width,height))

#Function to open webview on the main thread
def open_my_webview(url):
    global webview_window
    if webview_window is None:        
        open_button.config(command= lambda: open_my_webview(url), takefocus=0)
        create_my_webview_window()
        webview.start(debug=False, func=lambda:load_my_url(webview_window,url))
        close_my_webview(url)

#Function to ensure the webview window is closed
def close_my_webview(url):
    global webview_window
    if webview_window is not None:
        try:
            webview.destroy_window()
        except Exception:
            pass
        webview_window = None
    else:
        webview_window = None
        root.wm_deiconify()
        open_button.config(command= lambda: open_my_webview(url), takefocus=0)

root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_title("Open Webview")
#root.overrideredirect(True)

w,h = 100,100
root.wm_geometry(f'{w}x{h}+300+30')
root.wm_resizable(False,False)

root.wm_minsize(w, h) #just trying stuff here
root.wm_maxsize(w, h) #just trying stuff here

url = 'https://www.google.com'

#Create the buttons
open_button = tk.Button(root, text="Open WebView", command=lambda:open_my_webview(url), takefocus=0)
open_button.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

close_button = tk.Button(root, text="Close App", command=lambda:root.destroy(), takefocus=0)
close_button.grid(row = 1, column = 0, rowspan=1)

#Run the tkinter event loop
root.wm_state("normal") #just trying stuff here
root.wm_deiconify() #just trying stuff here
root.mainloop()

If I didn't write this correctly, or if I missed anything, let me know.  This is my 1st time.

You can create a menu for a webview window. Why do you need tkinter?

the original app is way bigger than the example shown. I merely gave that example to get help specifically with the resizing problem. sadly, your comment is of no help to me.

I was wondering why you use tkinter, since pywebview, like tkinter, is a tool for creating GUIs (differently). root.mainloop() starts the tkinter GUI loop to process events. webview.start(...) also starts its own GUI loop that blocks your tkinter application.

There is a standard webbrowser module that allows you to open a URL from a Python script.
